# Are there any rescue CD's which are bootable on UEFI and or UEFI with Secure Boot enabled?

Tags: boot, uefi, efi, secure-boot, rescue-disk

I'm looking for Rescue CD's like Hiren's Boot CD which allow me to boot without switching to BIOS or turning off Secure Boot. I had no luck finding such thing.

Is it even possible to launch such an utility with Secure Boot enabled?

How can I modify any Rescue CD to launch when in UEFI and Secure Boot enabled? (if possible)

Comment: Since only Microsoft’s keys are installed by default, if any, you probably won’t have any luck with this. Except perhaps installing Secure Boot keys is acceptable...?

Comment: Well I do always have a portable Windows To Go install with me, if that's possible then sure.

Comment: Several Linux distributions can function as rescue systems and support Secure Boot. Ubuntu, for instance, can be used in this way.